# How to define x-model in for-circle of checkboxes based on array?

Tags: alpine.js

in my Laravel 8 /  tailwindcss 2 / Alpinejs 2.8 app I fill set of checkboxex based on array like:

```
<template x-for="nextCategory in categories" :key="nextCategory.id">
    <tr class="p-4 mb-15">
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox"
                x-bind:id="'cbx_' + nextCategory.id" 
                name="cbx_Categories" 
                x-bind:value="nextCategory.id"
                class="p-4 checked:bg-blue-600"
            >
            <label :for="'cbx_' + nextCategory.id" class="whitespace-nowrap md:flex-shrink-0" 
            x-text="nextCategory.id+' : '+nextCategory.name">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right" x-text="nextCategory.ad_categories_count">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

The checkboxes are rendered ok, but I try to keep state of any checkbox element in array defined as :

```
  searchSelectedCategoryIds: [],
```

and use this array in checkbox x-model definition:

```
<template x-for="nextCategory in categories" :key="nextCategory.id">
    <tr class="p-4 mb-15">
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox"
                x-bind:id="'cbx_' + nextCategory.id" 
                name="cbx_Categories" 
                x-bind:value="nextCategory.id"
               x-model="searchSelectedCategoryIds"
               class="p-4 checked:bg-blue-600"
            >
            <label :for="'cbx_' + nextCategory.id" class="whitespace-nowrap md:flex-shrink-0" 
            x-text="nextCategory.id+' : '+nextCategory.name">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right" x-text="nextCategory.ad_categories_count">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

as result all by clicking on any checkbox all checkboxes are selected and searchSelectedCategoryIds
has value “on”

Which way is valid ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <div class="flex items-center justify-center p-8 m-10">

        <div class="flex justify-center w-screen h-screen bg-gray-100"  x-data="checkBoxTest()" >

            categories::<span x-text="categories.id"></span><br><hr>
            TestsearchSelectedCategoryIds::<span x-text="TestsearchSelectedCategoryIds"></span><br><hr>
                              <table x-show="categories.length">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Ads Number</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

  <template x-for="nextCategory in categories" :key="nextCategory.id">
    <tr class="p-4 mb-15">
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox"
                x-bind:id="'cbx_' + nextCategory.id" 
                name="cbx_Categories" 
                x-bind:value="nextCategory.id"
                class="p-4 checked:bg-blue-600"
                x-model="TestsearchSelectedCategoryIds"     
            >
            <label :for="'cbx_' + nextCategory.id" class="whitespace-nowrap md:flex-shrink-0" 
            x-text="nextCategory.id+' : '+nextCategory.name">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right" x-text="nextCategory.ad_categories_count">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
                                   </table>
  
  </div>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script>


function checkBoxTest() {
    return {
      TestsearchSelectedCategoryIds: '',
    
categories : [
  {
     ad_categories_count: 2,
     id: 1,
     name: "Laptops"
  },
  
  {
    ad_categories_count: 3,
    id: 2,
    name: "Computer Monitor"
  },
  
  {
    ad_categories_count: 4,
    id: 4,
    name: "Computer Accessories"
  }
    
]

    }}


    </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED TO BE LESS CONFUSING]

I need to see your `x-data`. Your `<template>` seems fine. I tried to get the value of `searchSelectedCategoryIds: [],` to be `"on"` and can only reproduce your result if:

- I set `searchSelectedCategoryIds: [],`; and
- I remove the `x-bind:value="nextCategory.id"` in the `<input>` attribute.

Meanwhile, if:

- I set `searchSelectedCategoryIds: '',` instead of `searchSelectedCategoryIds: [],` *(a `string` instead of an `array`)*; and
- I set the `x-bind:value="nextCategory.id"` in the `<input>` attribute;

I will get the the value of `true` which is also the wrong output.

AFAIK, the browser will determine the value of `<input type="checkbox">` if we don't set it. In this case, the browser sets it to `"on"`. So, the issue here is a failed binding but I cannot verify unless I can see your `x-data` structure. Here's my attempt to replicate but with everything set:

```
<form class="bg-gray-800">
  <div class="flex justify-center items-center max-w-lg mx-auto h-screen">
    <table x-data="formRender()" class="bg-gray-50">
      <caption class="bg-gray-100 font-light text-yellow-700 uppercase tracking-widest">Title</caption>
      <thead class="border-t border-gray-300 font-bold">
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Count</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="divide-y border-gray-300">
        <template x-for="nextCategory in categories" :key="nextCategory.id">
          <tr class="p-4 mb-15">
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" x-bind:id="'cbx_' + nextCategory.id" name="cbx_Categories" x-bind:value="nextCategory.id" x-model="searchSelectedCategoryIds" class="p-4 checked:bg-blue-600">
              <label :for="'cbx_' + nextCategory.id" class="whitespace-nowrap md:flex-shrink-0" x-text="nextCategory.id+' : '+nextCategory.name">
              </label>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right" x-text="nextCategory.ad_categories_count">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td class="bg-yellow-500 text-center" colspan="2">
            <output x-text=" 'Item checked: ' + searchSelectedCategoryIds"></output>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  function formRender() {
    return {
      categories: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'banana',
          ad_categories_count: 'one'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'apple',
          ad_categories_count: 'two'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'orange',
          ad_categories_count: 'three'
        }
      ],
      searchSelectedCategoryIds: [],
    }
  }
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/wanahmadfiras/pen/YzpmERK

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tring to salve this issue several days ago I created pen : https://codepen.io/sergeynilov/pen/vYyPrrE?editors=1010 which works ok, but putting this piece of code in Laravel 8 / tailwindcss 2 / Alpinejs 2.8 app it works with error as I wrote in my topic. I cannot catch why...

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK : this exsample in blade.php file does not work and I can not catch why?

Comment: I think I sound confusing, I mean your original code is okay. There's nothing wrong in it in the first place, I just want to try to replicate your error. Both values of `on` and `true` is the wrong way. You should put your `searchSelectedCategoryIds: [],` just like that as an `array`.

Comment: In your modified block, you shouldn't make the `x-model` for `<input type="checkbox">` with a `string`. It should be an `array` just like your original code. I was trying to replicate your error by making it a `string`. This `TestsearchSelectedCategoryIds: '',` in your modified block should be `TestsearchSelectedCategoryIds: [],`

Comment: I was reading Blade's [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#escaping-attribute-rendering) and thought of your question. Could it be because `:key="nextCategory.id` isn't escaped? Therefore Alpine is rendering your view without `key` which is [possible](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-for) at first but I assume that `:key` is needed for `x-model` to function? Maybe try `::key="nextCategory.id"`?

Comment: I tried this way and got error : ReferenceError: nextCategory is not defined

Comment: Okay I've tried using your code directly into a fresh project. We don't need to escape the `:key` and I use `searchSelectedCategoryIds: [],` and everything is working fine?

Comment: I refreshed last nopacked version of alpinejs and it works ok. @Wan Ahmad Firas, thanks your help was usefull